# In Windows Workflow 4 why is my state re-entering itself when I attempt to use only a conditional data trigger

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

I have a windows workflow state machine (VS2017 with the Sharepoint module added) with a number of states which has been working fine until I introduced an additional state with purely a data driven transition.

To attempt to explain: I have an entry state which is called 'New' and within the Entry for the New state I establish a boolean fact and set a variable internally on the state machine.

From the New state I then have a transition to another state, let's simply call the target state 'Yes' and this transition has ONLY a data condition which is whether or not my boolean fact is true. The 'trigger' part of the transition is left blank. I believe this is supported?

```
[Transition] New->Yes condition: "MyFact == true"
```

If I remove the condition above, then the workflow will automatically drop into the 'Yes' state. If I put the condition back in, then the workflow seems to transition and then go into some perpetual loop on itself. Does anyone have any advice as to how to go about figuring this out? If I put an empty sequence in the trigger I can put a breakpoint on that sequence and see it just get hit over and over and over again. The 'Yes' target state has a transition back to itself using another bookmark activity. So I don't understand where the loop has arrived.

I think the bottom line question is: are blank triggers supported with conditional data expressions? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to have anything in the Trigger section of a transition, this is supported in Windows Windows workflow, not sure why you are going in a perpetual loop, probably better if you edit your question and add some images of your state diagram.

Here is an example where the trigger is empty and I just have a condition on a variable defined in my state diagram, if it passes it goes into state 2

[image]